# How to add css as inline style to a div from an external stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap for styling a html page. There are some custom classes too. Here is the code.

```
<div class="row row-padded section-header">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 text-right">Sizes</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-padded">
        <div class="col-md-10 text-right">Title</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control small-input-box" id="title" value="14" />
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

HTML view for this code is ok. I want to create a snippet for this view. So that anyone can add this to their site and feel the styling of bootstrap. I only want to provide inline css.

After a button click, it will go to every div and there corresponding classes, for each class it will get all style from bootstrap.min.css, my custom.css file and insert those in that div as inline style. Is there any way to do this using javascript or jquery?

Comment: store said css as a string variable, that should be  the simplest way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

Comment: Injecting 97kb of minified CSS into each element sounds like a bad idea :) Why not inject `<style>.row .row-padded .section-header { @import bootstrap.min.css; }</style>` instead?